# Copy/tables keeping old indexes intact in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, oracle-sqldeveloper

[image]

I have two tables in my schema. Table1 is old and Table 2 is new, and now somehow I want Table2 to be somehow copied/renamed to Table1. At the same time I want to preserve the indexes in the old table --> Table1 after rename/copy.

I am using SQL Developer to achieve this. I hope I have explained my doubt clearly.

1. If I drop the Table1 I lose the Indexes.
2. I cannot rename Table2 to Table1 until its deleted.
3. I could not see option to copy indexes on sql developer.

Comment: Simply create the two indexes on table2 and rename if necessary after you've dropped table1. Indexes are generated from data in a table; you can't lift-and-shift them to another table; you need to regenerate them for the new table.

Comment: Extract the DDL to create the indexes, and run them on the renamed/copied Table2...

Comment: Why can't you re-create the indexes? Or simply copy data from t2 to t1?

Comment: What is your *primary goal*? Do you want to **reorganize the table**?

Answer (score 1):

Truncate `table1` and re-insert the data:

```
truncate table table1;

insert into table1 ( . . . )
    select . . .
    from table2;
```

If the two tables have the same columns in the same order, you can do the insert without listing columns:

```
insert into table1
    select *
    from table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this sequence of steps?

```
-- original table
create table table2 
(x number);

create index table2_idx on table2(x);


-- now create the copy table
create table table1
as
select * from table2;

-- create new index
create index table1_idx on table1(x);

-- now switch 
drop table table2;
rename table1 to table2;
```

Substitute for your own index definietion and names.

You find this in the index `DDL` in the table overview tab `SQL`.